# function working in console but not in code

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am currently working on an event calendar which has interactive modals that pull data from an event API.

I would like users to be able to close the modal when clicking on the "x" as well as when they click anywhere on the page.

In the current set up, there is a dropdown menu that lists that allows you to select the month and you are able to click out of the menu when pressing anywhere on the page.  However, I cannot get this to work for the modal.

I can trigger the functions within the console but not in the code itself.  The "x" button closes the modal just fine, but not when clicking anywhere on the page.

I am using fullCalendar to render the calendar and pass data into the modal.  In addition, we utilize drupal, php, and twig.  (code base it kind of a mess, but thats another issue.)

I have included the code that runs the month dropdown where the click anywhere functionality works just fine.  The modal code is located at the bottom.  I know the code can be simplified, but for troubleshooting sake I broke it way down.

I have tried .show() and .hide(), executing the function within fullCalendar and without, using $() as well as jQuery() and currently am attempting to toggle the classes and do the show/hide in css.  From what I've read on here, this could be due to the page not loading fully before trying to manipulate the DOM.  But, seeing as how this functionality works in the dropdowns I don't think that is it.

```
(function ($) {
  /***| * TABS |***/
  $(document).on('click keypress', '.calendar__tabs--title', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (e.which === 13 || e.type === 'click') {
      $('.calendar__tabs--title').removeClass('active');
      $('.calendar__views div').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('tab') == id) {
          $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click keypress', '.changeMonth', function (e) {});

  //Dropdown
  var sel = $('.selected');
  var options = $('.options');
  var current = $('.current');
  var monthChoice = $('.monthChoice');
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var currDate = new Date();
  var currMonth = currDate.getMonth();

  monthChoice.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($('.options').css("display") != "none") {
      current.text(monthNames[currMonth]);
      var date = moment().format("YYYY");
      var newMonth = e.target.getAttribute('value').length == 1 ? "0" + e.target.getAttribute('value') : e.target.getAttribute('value');
      var newDate = date + "-" + newMonth + "-01";
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', $.fullCalendar.moment(newDate));
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('div').removeClass('selected');
      options.hide();
    } else {
      current.text(monthNames[currMonth]);
      options.show();
    }
  });
  if (options) {
    $('body').click(function (e) {
      options.hide();
    });
  }

  options.children('div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    current.text($(this).text());
    var date = (parseInt(sel.attr('value'), 10) < parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('value'), 10)) ? moment().format("YYYY") : moment().add(1, 'year').format("YYYY");
    var newMonth = e.target.getAttribute('value').length == 1 ? "0" + e.target.getAttribute('value') : e.target.getAttribute('value');
    var newDate = date + "-" + newMonth + "-01";
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', $.fullCalendar.moment(newDate));
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('div').removeClass('selected');
    options.hide();
  });

  //Views

  jQuery(".calendar__tabs--title.month").click(function () {
    jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
  })
  jQuery(".calendar__tabs--title.week").click(function () {
    jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
  })


  //Events

  const events = JSON.parse(drupalSettings.events);
  console.log(events);

  //Calender
  jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "title prev,next",
      right: ""
    },
    columnHeaderHtml: function (mom) {
      var view = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
      if (view.name === "agendaWeek") {
        return mom.format("DD") + "<br>" + mom.format("ddd");
      }
      if (view.name === "month") {
        return mom.format("ddd");
      }
    },
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    navLinks: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    editable: false,
    titleFormat: "MMMM",
    displayEventTime: false,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    background: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    minTime: "09:00:00",
    maxTime: "22:00:00",
    slotDuration: "00:60:00",
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    height: "auto",
    selectable: false,
    slotLabelFormat: 'h' + ':00' + '(:mm)a',
    buttonIcons: true,
    buttonText: false,
    htmlEscape: false,
    events: events.map(function (event) {

      return {
        title: event.name,  
        description: event.description,
        location: event.locations,
        start: event.date_range.start_date,
        end: event.date_range.end_date,
        event_id: event.nid,
        event_image: event.media[0].url,
      }
    }),

    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {

      var eventURL = "https://www.mallofamerica.com/events/view/";
      jQuery("#event-img").attr('src', event.event_image);
      jQuery("#event-header").text(event.title);
      jQuery("#modal-title").text(event.title);
      jQuery("#more-info").text(event.description);
      jQuery("#event-link").attr('href', eventURL + event.event_id);
      jQuery("#myModal").addClass("activate");


      jQuery(".close-button").click(function (e) {
        var modal = jQuery("#myModal")
        modal.removeClass("activate")
      })

      // jQuery("body").click(function (e) {
      //   var modal = jQuery("#myModal")
      //   if (modal.hasClass("activate")) {
      //     modal.removeClass("activate")
      //   }
      // })

      // $("#add-cal").click(function () {
      //   // $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEventSources') 
      //   $("#calender").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      //   var subject = event.title;
      //   var description = event.description;
      //   var location = "";
      //   var start = event.start._i;
      //   var end = event.end._i;
      //   console.log(subject, description, location, start, end)
      //   var cal = ics();
      //   cal.addEvent(subject, description, location, start, end);
      //   cal.download('event')
      //   // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

      // })
    },
  })




}(jQuery)); /* end jquery */
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `jQuery(".close-button").click(function` outside of the `eventClick: function()` ? And then closing the modal with `jQuery("#myModal").hide()` inside it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution!

I had to exclude two divs from the .hide() function so when a user clicks on the event the modal would still show.

```
  jQuery(".close-button").on("click", function(e){
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#myModal").hide();
  })

  jQuery("body").click(function(e) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).is('.fc-day-grid-event, .fc-title')){
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery("#myModal").show();
    } else {
      jQuery("#myModal").hide();
    }
  })
```